# Swift CryptoKit AES Encryption and Javascript AES Decryption

Tags: swift, aes, cryptojs, cryptoswift

I need to encrypt a value in an iOS app using CryptoKit and send it to a server, which will attempt to decrypt that value using a JavaScript Crypto Library (Right now, we're thinking CryptoJS, but open to other examples). There are a lot of questions on this topic, but I haven't come across any clear answers with updated examples, so I thought I'd describe my approach.

**AES Encryption Using Swift**

```
let key = "SomePrivateKey"
let dateToEncrypt = Date().toISOFormat().data(using: .utf8)
let val = try CryptoKit.AES.GCM.seal(
    datToEncrypt ?? Data(),
    using: .init(data: Array(key.utf8))
)
return val.ciphertext.base64EncodedString()
```

**AES Decryption Using CryptoJS**

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, myPassword);
return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

**Expected Output**

The decrypted string is an ISO Formatted Date

**Actual Output**

The decryption fails due to poorly formatted UTF-8 data, or the decryption succeeds but with a totally random value then what I expected (looks like a hex value of some sort)

Comment: CryptoJS uses CBC mode by default, and doesn’t support GCM at all. What kind of browser support do you need?

Comment: Interesting, our app is fully mobile right now with our backend running on NodeJS, so whatever can support mobile would help

Comment: So the JavaScript here is server-side only?

Comment: Yes, the JavaScript here is server side

Comment: Which version of Node.js?

Comment: @Ry- we are using NodeJS 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CryptoJS uses CBC mode by default, and doesn’t support GCM at all. You shouldn’t use CryptoJS at the best of times (the native and better-designed Web Crypto API is to be preferred), but especially not on the server, where Node.js has always had [a native crypto module](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/crypto.html).

First, [include the GCM nonce and tag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/aes/gcm/sealedbox/3344730-combined), which are essential components:

```swift
return val.combined!.base64EncodedString()
```

Then, in Node.js, using the layout as described in the documentation for the `combined` property:

> The data layout of the combined representation is: nonce, ciphertext, then tag.

```js
// where `sealedBox` is a buffer obtained with `Buffer.from(encryptedString, 'base64')`
let nonce = sealedBox.slice(0, 12);
let ciphertext = sealedBox.slice(12, -16);
let tag = sealedBox.slice(-16);
let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-gcm', key, nonce);
decipher.setAuthTag(tag);
let decrypted =
    Buffer.concat([decipher.update(ciphertext), decipher.final()])
    .toString('utf8');
```

Once that’s working, don’t forget to fix your key, because `.init(data: Array(key.utf8))` is very uncomfortable (your AES keys should not be valid UTF-8).

- If you’re starting with a password (for a good reason, not just because it seemed convenient), use a PBKDF to get key bytes. (Unfortunately, no PBKDF implementations are built into CryptoKit.)

  … but if the good reason is that it’s a user-provided password and you’re claiming to provide security, *please* get someone experienced with use of cryptography to review your work.
- Otherwise, generate a random key safely and [decode it from a Base64](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/3126625-init) or hex string. No UTF-8.

  ```bash
  node -p 'crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("base64")'
  ```

  And get someone experienced with use of cryptography to review your work anyway.

Comment: Thank you, this is great so far. When i try to createDecipherIv, i get the error 'Invalid key length.' I generated a new key using the node -p method you added, and I am using the combined value as well

Comment: @MichaelJajou: `key` there should be base64-decoded already, e.g. `let key = Buffer.from(keyBase64, 'base64');`.

Comment: That solved the invalid key length issue, thanks. Now we have a new error: ```Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data at Decipheriv.final (node:internal/crypto/cipher:193:29)```

Comment: Ah I assume this is because I am missing the auth tag, let me add that in

Comment: Actually it looks like the auth tag is present

Comment: @MichaelJajou: Ah, sorry, I typoed `.slice(12, 16)` instead of `.slice(12, -16)`.